# installing ReditorSupport in VScode - Error

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

When I try to install `ReditorSupport` though the vscode extension manager I get a 'Failed to install 'reditorsupport.R' ' error.

I then accept the suggestion to try and download it manually.  The download is successful, getting a file named `REditorSupport.r-2.5.3.vsix`.

When i try and install using this downloaded package I don't get any errors, nor does any installation occur.

if I follow a link to the webpage for the extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r
and click on the green `Install` it opens vscode and asks me "Would you like to install the R extension?".
When i click `install` I get a 'Server returned 404' error.

I should also note that I can install other extensions without error or warning through the extension manager.

Can you help me get this installed in vscode?

Comment: What happens if you try to install a different extension? I'm wondering whether the problem is specific to the R extension or affecting all extensions.

Comment: @andycraig, any other extension I try installs in seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you did include that info in your original question. This is a strange one. If you don't get an answer here please consider opening an Issue at the extension's repo: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues

Comment: I think this was resolved via discussion at the extension's repo? An answer might be useful for anyone who encounters this problem in the future so if you post one I'll be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by upgrading my vscode install.

Version where the issue occured:  1.36.1
Version where no issue occurred:  1.72.2